# approximate $C^1$ function by Holder function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, geometric-measure-theory

I am trying to prove the following Lemma:

> Suppose $u$: $\mathcal R^N\to \mathbb R$ is $C^1$. Then for each
>   $\epsilon>0$, there exists a $C^{1,\alpha}$ function $\tilde f$ such
>   that  $$ \mathcal L^N\{x,\,\,\tilde f(x)\neq f(x)\}\leq \epsilon, $$
>   for any $0<\alpha<1$.

I am trying to use [Whitney's extension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitney_extension_theorem) but so far I have no luck... Any help is really welcome!

Comment: Are we on a bounded set?

Comment: @zhw. Yea, sure

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? If not, what about the "zeroth order" version of the question? i.e. can every $C^0$ function be approximated by a $C^\alpha$ function in this sense?